# Php memcache extend data time

Tags: php

Im using memcache with php. Upon storing data I set how long data should last (30minutes i.e.), then in that time, this data is being updated many times, but I believe timer doesnt update, right?

Why I say so? Because it doesnt matter if I update my data with new timer, but it still gets destroyed after 30minutes.

A lot better way of using memcached for me would be extending time for X key data.

**Should I delete data stored in memory before updating (to increase deletion timer) it or is there any other ways?**

edit: mistake, I use memcache, not memache**d**

**SOLVED**
For memcacheD use Ben's answer. But for memcache, use this one http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php#84032

Thanks!

Comment: If it didn't update the timer, why would `replace()` take an expiration time?

Comment: True, using replace with an additional check if data is stored solves the problem. http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php#84032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$memcached->touch($key, $duration);` to increase the duration the data is stored.

[Memcached::touch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.touch.php)

Comment: I dont see touch on my memcached localhost, so I believe I need to update memcached to newer version. Do you know simpliest way to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you're using memcached and not memcache?